# Overfull \vbox errors with beamer, newcent and split outer theme

Tags: beamer

The following ECM produces `Overfull \vbox` errors.

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{newcent}
\useoutertheme{split}
\begin{document}
\section{s1}
\section{s2}
\section{s3}
\section{s4}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Errors from `.log`:

```log
Overfull \vbox (0.70264pt too high) detected at line 5

Overfull \vbox (0.70264pt too high) has occurred while \output
```

Note: no error without `newcent` package.

How to remove these errors?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a workaround:

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newcent}
\useoutertheme{split}
%%% workaround
\newlength\myfontsize
\setlength\myfontsize{5.96pt}
\setbeamerfont*{section in head/foot}{size*={\myfontsize}{\myfontsize}}
\setbeamerfont*{subsection in head/foot}{size*={\myfontsize}{\myfontsize}}
%%%
\begin{document}
\section{s1}
\section{s2}
\section{s3}
\section{s4}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

There is no longer an error message but the value of `\myfontsize` is found by trial and error. In addition, it changes if we change the size of the default font.

PS: I tried to modify the `header` template defined by `split theme` (in `beamerouterthemesplit.sty`) but without success.